# Initialise tensors with ones in tensorflow 1

Tags: tensorflow, variables, initialization

I want to initialise a variable declared using get_variable function with 1s . 
I tried the following methods :

1.`tf.get_variable(name = 'yd1', shape = shape_t, dtype = tf.float32,initializer = tf.ones())`

Error received -> TypeError: ones() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

2. `tf.get_variable(name = 'yd1', shape = shape_t ,dtype = tf.float32,initializer = tf.ones(shape=shape_t))`

Error received -> ValueError("If initializer is a constant, do not specify shape.")

What is the best way to initialise a variable with ones?
tf.zeros_initializer can be used to initialise with 0s, but there is no equivalent for ones in tf 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`tf.ones_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones_initializer):

```py
tf.get_variable(name='yd1', shape=shape_t, dtype=tf.float32,
                initializer=tf.ones_initializer())
```

Alternatively, as the second error message says, you can use a constant value, but then do not pass a shape:

```py
tf.get_variable(name='yd1', initializer=tf.ones(shape=shape_t, dtype=tf.float32))
```

Answer (score 0):

tf.ones_initializer is not available in tf 1, It was introduced in tf 2.

The following code does the work

```
tf.get_variable(name = 'yd1', shape = shape_t ,dtype = tf.float32,initializer = tf.constant_initializer(1))
```